# Is there a way to preserve pixel values of an image after padding?

Tags: python, numpy, padding

I am working with two images `im0` and `im1` that have different shapes *(512, 512,3)* and *(217, 317, 3*) respectively. I wanted to add padding on the smaller image in order to make it the same size as the other one but after using

```
im1 = cv2.copyMakeBorder( im1, top = 200, bottom = 95, left = 100, right = 95, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

I get 0 values in the images array

```
print(im1)

  [[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]...
```

and I was expecting to get the existing values plus some 0 due to the padding like

```
    [[ 34  58  36]
  [ 39  63  41]
  [ 40  64  42]
  ...
  [ 47  81 116]
  [ 47  81 118]
  [ 47  81 118]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```

Does anyone know to fix this so I can have both the existing values along with the padding values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.pad` for this.

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
desired_height = 7
desired_width = 8
pad_value = 0

height, width = img.shape

print(img)

if height % desired_height != 0:
    padding = ((0, desired_height - (height % desired_height)), (0, 0))
    img = np.pad(img, padding, mode="constant", constant_values=pad_value)

if width % desired_width != 0:
    padding = ((0, 0), (0, desired_width - (width % desired_width)))
    img = np.pad(img, padding, mode="constant", constant_values=pad_value)

print(img)
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

[[ 0  1  2  3  4  0  0  0]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9  0  0  0]
 [10 11 12 13 14  0  0  0]
 [15 16 17 18 19  0  0  0]
 [20 21 22 23 24  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But in order to get the padding for both height and width I used only one if statement and did it like this
 if height % desired_height != 0 and width % desired_width != 0: